# Electrochemical cell potential - Prigogine book

Tags: thermodynamics, electrostatics, physical-chemistry

I'm trying to understand equation 10.2.14 from Prigogine's book "Modern thermodynamics":

$V=\frac{\tilde{A}}{nF}=\frac{1}{nF}\left(\mu_X^R+\mu_Y^L-\mu_{Xred}^R-\mu_{Yox}^L\right) - \left( \phi^R-\phi^L \right)=V_{cell}-\left( \phi^R-\phi^L \right)$.

In this equation the leftmost term is a voltage $V$ whereas the rightmost term is precisely the electrostatic potential difference between both electrodes. Then, what is $V$? In the book derivation it is traced back to the electrostatic potential drop of a conductor wire connecting the electrodes, but then this should be equal to $\left( \phi^R-\phi^L \right)$ and then $V_{cell}$ would be $0$. So I think it is an error of Prigogine's book and in fact I haven't seen that equation with that "$V$" in any other book.

I have figured out that the mistake is in the derivation: assuming that the entropy production of the whole system is the same that the entropy production of the connecting wire is what leads in the text to identifying that conducting voltage drop $V$ with the quantity $\frac{\tilde{A}}{nF}$. Indeed, the books says "in equilibrium, $V=0$", but having a conducting wire interconnecting both electrodes in equilibrium would be the  trivial equilibrium situation when there is no EMF after the complete discharge of the cell, and then of course V=0.

Could you throw a bit of light on this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Clarification: "A" is the affinity of the cell.

Comment: just a thought, nothing more - the cell under equilibrium and no current flowing in the external circuit will have a voltage across the terminals let's say it's 1.5V . But when you attach a load and make current flow (or pump current between the electrodes of an electrolytic cell), you no longer are in equilibrium and the voltage will drop (or increase) due to further oxidation and reductions required to supply the current. From a circuital pov this is modeled by the internal resistance of the cell, but is actually due to the fact that you are moving away from the I=0 line in the V-I chart.